# SqlCommand maximum parameters exception at 2099 parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am batching different queries in one SqlCommand stopping the queries batch when I hit the 2100 parameter limit. If my batch has 2100 or 2099 parameters I still get the exception.

The following test code throws 'too many parameters exception' even if the number of parameters is less than 2100.

```
var parametersMax = 2099;

var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
connection.Open();

var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, parametersMax);

var query = string.Format("SELECT {0}", String.Join(", ", enumerable.Select(s => string.Format("P{0} = @p{0}",s))));

var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

foreach(var i in enumerable)
    command.Parameters.Add(string.Format("p{0}",i), i);

// here: command.Parameters.Count is 2099

var reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // throws: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.
```

Considering the exception message and the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx I was expecting to be able to have 2100 parameters in one query, but this doesn't seem to be true. Does anyone know why? Am I missing something?

(I am using Sql Server 2008 R2)

Comment: What are you using this large number of parameters for? Have you considered using a table valued parameter instead?

Comment: Does it work with 2098/2097/etc. I think there is a ReturnValue parameter that SQL had by default.

Comment: I cannot use that by design, I'm fine with splitting the queries in multiple batches. I just wanted to know why I cannot use 2100 parameters as it says.

Comment: Won't an `Enumerable.Range` of 0 to 2099 create 2100 parameters? Does it work if the range is 1 to 2099?

Comment: @ipr101 - `command.Parameters.Count` is 2099 as specified in the OP.

Comment: @My Other Me, I thought of that but if it is a default behavior why would the documentation say 2100?
I also tried to put NO COUNT ON but I still get the error on 2099 parameters.
With 2098 works fine, that's the limit I configured now.
I also tried to execute 2 select queries in the same test batch and the limit was always 2098.

Comment: @ipr101 Enumerable.Range(0, 2099) creates an enumeration of 2099 elements starting from 0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

Comment: @crossy - Sorry, got that wrong!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The command sent to SQL Server is

```
exec sp_executesql 
          N'SELECT P0 = @p0, P1 = @p1, P2 = @p2...',
          N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int...',
          @p0=0,@p1=1,@p2=2...
```

Note that 2 of the parameter slots in the call to `sp_executesql` are taken up with the `NVARCHAR` strings for query text and the parameter definitions thus "only" leaving 2,098 free for you to use.

Comment: I was in front of this error (There are too many parameters in this EXECUTE statement. The maximum number is 2100.) realizing that the problem is the sp_executesql parameters count.
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: +1 for this answer.  I had the same thing happening with me.  VS reported command.Parameters.Count was exactly 2100 and SQL Server was indicating that I had more than 2100 parameters.  My 3rd grade education told me something was amiss.  With some experimentation I found that 2098 was the true maximum number of parameters.  So, the error message is misleading from a ADO.NET perspective to say the least.  I'm setting my max to 2090 in case Microsoft changes their ADO.NET implementation.