# Is it possible to create single SQL query for dozens of UPDATE statements? Should it increase performace? How should it look like in my case?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have a problem. In code below there is a `foreach` loop, where is created query string for each object `truck` inside of `trucks` collection. The loop iterates 100 times (100 objects in the collection, for the example). And method with the loop is called 2000 times.

I resigned from using of ORM to get better performance. But, unfortunatelly, I am still disapointed a bit with code execution speed.

Please note, that for each iterated object there is created `string query`, that looks, for the example, like this:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.Trucks 
SET OfficialNumber = '5124095' 
, Status = 'Undefined' 
, PerformancesUpdate = @PerformancesUpdate
, PictureLink = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/photos/middle////.jpg'
WHERE TruckId = 405664;
```

and next, after parsing `command.Parameters`, if they exists (in this case `@PerformancesUpdate`), the query is sent via library method with `int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute SQL`. And so on, 100 times. Please note, that query string depends on object properties, so every case will be different a bit.

**Here are my questions**. I am wondering, is it possible to create one query for all 100 objects in the loop and sending it at once? If yes, should it increase performance? If yes, How the sample query should look like?

And here is the code that creates loop, where are created and executed SQL queries:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection(_connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    connection.Open();


                    foreach (SomeObject truck in trucks)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Updating " + counter++ + " of " + trucks.Count);

                        //clean up string for basic data
                        truck.Status = CleanUpStringCases(truck.Status);
                        truck.Destination = CleanUpStringCases(truck.Destination);
                        //clean up string for full AIS data
                        if (dataType == "full")
                        {
                            truck.TruckType = CleanUpStringCases(truck.TruckType);
                        }

                        //PARSE

                        SomeObject existing = new SomeObject();

                        //find existing truck to be updated
                        if (truck.OfficialNumber > 0) existing = _context.trucks.Where(v => v.OfficialNumber == truck.OfficialNumber).FirstOrDefault();
                        StringBuilder querySb = new StringBuilder();

                        if (existing != null)
                        {
                            //update for basic data
                            querySb.Append("UPDATE dbo." + _trucksTableName + " SET OfficialNumber = '" + truck.OfficialNumber + "'");
                            if (existing.MNCI == 0) if (truck.MNCI.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , MNCI = '" + truck.MNCI + "'");
                            if (truck.LatestActivity.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , LatestActivity = @LatestActivity");
                            if (truck.ETA.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , ETA = @ETA");
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(truck.Status)) querySb.Append(" , Status = '" + truck.Status + "'");
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(truck.Destination)) querySb.Append(" , Destination = '" + truck.Destination + "'");
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(truck.Area)) querySb.Append(" , Area = '" + truck.Area + "'");

                            if (truck.HeadingTo.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , HeadingTo = @HeadingTo");
                            if (truck.Lat.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , Lat = @Lat");
                            if (truck.Lon.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , Lon = @Lon");
                            if (truck.Speed.HasValue)
                            {
                                querySb.Append(" , Speed = @Speed");
                                if ((existing.SpeedMax < truck.Speed || existing.SpeedMax == null) && truck.Speed != 0) querySb.Append(" , SpeedMax = @Speed"); //update speed max
                            }

                            //string for full AIS data
                            if (dataType == "full")
                            {
                                if (truck.PerformancesUpdate.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , PerformancesUpdate = @PerformancesUpdate");
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(truck.TruckType)) querySb.Append(" , TruckType = '" + truck.TruckType + "'");
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(truck.PictureLink)) querySb.Append(" , PictureLink = '" + truck.PictureLink + "'");
                                if (truck.LOA.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , LOA = '" + truck.LOA + "'");
                                if (truck.Height.HasValue) querySb.Append(" , Height = '" + truck.Height + "'");
                            }

                            querySb.Append(" WHERE truckId = " + existing.truckId + "; ");
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            string query = querySb.ToString();

                            command.CommandText = query;
                            if (query.Contains("LatestActivity ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LatestActivity", truck.LatestActivity);
                            if (query.Contains("ETA ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ETA", truck.ETA);
                            if (query.Contains("PerformancesUpdate ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformancesUpdate", truck.PerformancesUpdate);
                            if (query.Contains("HeadingTo ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeadingTo", truck.HeadingTo);
                            if (query.Contains("Lat ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lat", truck.Lat);
                            if (query.Contains("Lon ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lon", truck.Lon);
                            if (query.Contains("Speed ="))
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Speed", truck.Speed);

                            command.CommandTimeout = 30;
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                            int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute SQL
                            command.Parameters.Clear();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Solution:
**Martin`s** approach is marked as a solution. And answering question about increasing performance, after testing his approach on local DB I can tell, that DB update speed increases directly proportional on quantity of updated rows in single query. For the example, when updating 300 rows, it took me around 30s, together with API requests. When updating 1000 rows, it all takes around 80s. And, as guys mentioned, the only limitation is **the number of parameters**, so I am just converting doubles and DateTime to SQL format, getting rid of parameters, and *voila*.

Comment: https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/370928/Inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-SQL-query-using-C-Net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send multiple update commands on one operation.

You would need to add the commands to your string builder and number the SQL parameters.

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()
var querySb = new Stringbuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < trucks.Count; i++)
{
    [...]

    if (truck.Speed.HasValue)
    {
        querySb.Append(" , Speed = @Speed" + i);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Speed" + i, truck.Speed);
    }

    querySb.AppendLine();
}
command.CommandText = querySb.ToString();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You might create smaller batches of rows (not send all rows at once), maximum number of parameters in one command is 2,098.

Comment: Remember limit of parameters per one query execution.

Comment: @Fabio Thank you for this point, the number of parameters is 2,098, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050091/sqlcommand-maximum-parameters-exception-at-2099-parameters

Comment: I understand that in the world of answering people online you can't know people DataType. So `AddWithValue` is great because you don't have that issue. But I will advocate about using the `Add` method. It's been deprecated for at least 5 years now.

Comment: After testing your approach on local DB I can tell, that DB update speed increases directly proportional on quantity of updated rows in single query. For the example, when updating 300 rows, it took me around 30s, together with API requests. When updating 1000 rows, it all takes around 80s. And, as you guys mentioned, the only limitation is **the number of parameters**, so I am just converting `doubles` and `DateTime` to SQL format, getting rid of parameters, and _voila_. Thank you for the suggested approach. I will mark it as solution.

Comment: @bakunet, _getting rid of parameters_ - this is a mistake from performance and **security** point of view

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using some kind of bulk operations, since multiple separate db roundtrips produces excess overhead (as you have noticed).

Bulk updates can be implemented i.e with following methods:

- By using [external library](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions) which is specialized on high-speed Bulk operations
- By crafting sql stored procedure which takes array of data as parameter. More information about table-valued parameters can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine
- Store all the rows with a [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operation to a temporary table and run the T-SQL [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operation from temp table to actual data table with a single database transaction.